# Criação de aplicação com Salvamento na nuvem apenas para usuários premium

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, react-native

Trabalho com react-native e tenho interesse em criar uma aplicação que salva em um banco de dados na nuvem apenas para usuários premium.
O usuário iria persistir normalmente no aparelho local, porém, caso tivesse um plano premium no meu app, os dados seriam sincronizados num banco de dados na nuvem.

Atualmente pesquisei soluções como Firebase do google e Aws da amazon porém não achei sobre como permitir persistir apenas offline seguindo algum critério.
Não faz sentido ter a aplicação toda salva no firebase por exemplo, pois com o tempo o plano vai começar a ficar caro e a quantidade de usuários que pagam não iriam compensar pelos usuários free que utilizam o serviço.

**Eu quero dicas de artigos para ler, tecnologias que devo aprender ou direcionamento do que devo pesquisar para adquirir o conhecimento necessário para fazer algo do tipo e dicas de qual conhecimento preciso ter para tal.**

Atualmente as tecnologias de backend que tenho conhecimento são:

**NodeJs**: 3/5

**C#**: 4/5

Comment: Não entendo porque minha pergunta está fora do escopo. Se puder me auxiliar onde eu posso postar eu agradeceria.